Migrate to the latest version of NX, but not Angular
I have an Angular mono-repo that utilizes NX for workspace tooling. I am currently on Angular v17 and NX v18.2.4.
According to the NX compatibility matrix, the current LTS Angular versions are recommended to use the latest NX version. At the time of this post, the LTS versions are v17-v19 (v19 just released).
The issue I am running into is that I would like to start by migrating to Angular v18, as I have dependencies that have not yet released a version for Angular v19, and then I can migrate to Angular v19 in a month or so. Whenever I do nx migrate latest, it tries to migrate the workspace all the way up to Angular v19
I have tried using nx migrate @angular/cli@18.0.0, but that results in only updating @angular/cli.
I can just update NX to v19.6.0 (A version after Angular v18 was released, but before v19 was released) and that migrates correctly. But I feel like I'm missing something that would allow me to keep NX up to date.
Any insight would be useful, thanks!

Did you try to do nx migrate latest and then revert the angular version in package.json to v18 and then npm install? Should work. If that does not work, you're better off just waiting for your dependencies to be updated and ready for Angular v19.

There is a migration step in migrations.json to update Angular packages, so I have a bit of a feeling that would cause some issues down the line, because the next time you run npm i after the migration is applied, node_modules would be updated with Ng19. I felt it was odd that they recommended latest NX version for all LTS versions if you needed a workaround if that was the case anyways.
